# tabBarController navigation problem/question

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a simple tabBarController application where the user can navigate around 3 views.

In one of the views I have a UIButton that when touched moves the user to a fourth view. the problem is that the new view doesn't have the tab bar navigation visible.

what do I need to do to the fourth view to have it also use the tabBarController feature set.

thanks for any help

here's the code that transitions to the fourth view when a UIButton is touched:

```
-(IBAction) nextQuestion {

        Question2 *q2 = [[Question2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Question2" bundle:nil];

        q2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

        [self presentModalViewController:q2 animated:YES];

        [q2 release];

}
```

Comment: Post your code. We have no idea how you implemented this, so we can't tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: ok, I added the code that makes the transition to the new/fourth view page. the only problem is that the tabViewController disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modal view controller always takes up the entire screen. Its purpose is to provide a *modal* interface that does not let the user interact with other parts of the UI until they dismiss the modal view.

To display another view inside a tab, you could make the root controller of that tab a navigation controller. A button tap would then push the `Question 2` controller on the nav controller's stack.